# Custom scroll with arrows, only when the text is higher than the <div /> height

Tags: jquery, css, jscrollpane

I am using jScrollPane for custom scrollbars, in my case I need to use arrows. You know, designers... Well I've a working code that works, but I i need to disable (display:none;) the arrows if the text isn't bigger than the `<div />`.

The code and example: http://jsfiddle.net/Mdy2r/2/

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you upgrade to the current version of jScrollPane [http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/] then you will be able to style the arrows so that they disappear when they are disabled (or otherwise unnecessary):

```
.jspArrow.jspDisabled
{
    display: none;
}
```